# Authentication for GitHub API v4 with Apollo-Client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-api, apollo, apollo-client

GitHub's new GraphQL API requires authentication with a token as the previous version. So, how do we add a 'Header' information into the HttpLink inside `Apollo-Client`?

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({ uri: 'https://api.github.com/graphql' }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Update - 10/2021

Using `@apollo/client` and  `graphql` packages:

```js
import { 
  ApolloClient, 
  InMemoryCache, 
  gql, 
  HttpLink 
} from "@apollo/client";
import { setContext } from "@apollo/client/link/context";

const token = "YOUR_TOKEN";

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Token ${token}` : null,
    },
  };
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(
    new HttpLink({ uri: "https://api.github.com/graphql" })
  ),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

client
  .query({
    query: gql`
      query ViewerQuery {
        viewer {
          login
        }
      }
    `,
  })
  .then((resp) => console.log(resp.data.viewer.login))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

#### Original post - 12/2017

You can define authorization header using `apollo-link-context`, check [the header section](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/664d8c1311ece206d9ee93af3f0a808d35cd9572/docs/source/recipes/authentication.md#header)

A complete example for using apollo-client for Github API would be :

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const token = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null,
    }
  }
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(new HttpLink({ uri: 'https://api.github.com/graphql' })),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

client.query({
  query: gql`
    query ViewerQuery {
      viewer {
        login
     }
    }
  `
})
  .then(resp => console.log(resp.data.viewer.login))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```