# GraphQL complex cURL query (GitHub API v4)

Tags: json, curl, github, graphql, github-api

I'm trying to do a GraphQL query to GitHub v4 API in a JS app but I'm having a "Problem with JSON" error.
So I'm trying to do it with cURL but it seems to have a problem I can't see.

```
    curl -H "Authorization: token bearer" -H  "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d '{ "query": "query {
      viewer {                                                             
        watching(first: 3, orderBy: {field: UPDATED_AT, direction: DESC}) {
          nodes {                                                                                            
            refs(refPrefix: \"refs/heads/\", orderBy: {direction: DESC, field: TAG_COMMIT_DATE}, last: 100) {
              nodes {   
                target {         
                  ... on Commit {       
                    history(first: 10) {
                      ...CommitFragment
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }          
      rateLimit {
        limit
        cost     
        remaining
        resetAt
      }
    }

    fragment CommitFragment on CommitHistoryConnection {
      nodes {  
        message 
        author {
          name               
          avatarUrl(size: 30)
        }
      }
    }
```

I want to mention that the request is working on the [github.com/v4/explorer/](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/) website.
And I have escaped the quotes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the query is JSON stringified, in your request you add new lines in the JSON string field `query` which is not permitted :

```bash
curl -H "Authorization: token YOUR_TOKEN" \
     -H  "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -d '{ 
          "query": "{ viewer { watching(first: 3, orderBy: {field: UPDATED_AT, direction: DESC}) { nodes { refs(refPrefix: \"refs/heads/\", orderBy: {direction: DESC, field: TAG_COMMIT_DATE}, last: 100) { nodes { target { ... on Commit { history(first: 10) { ...CommitFragment } }}}}}}} rateLimit { limit cost remaining resetAt}}fragment CommitFragment on CommitHistoryConnection { nodes { message author { name avatarUrl(size: 30) } } }"
      }' https://api.github.com/graphql
```

You can also use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to remove new lines and escape double quotes :

```
token="YOUR_TOKEN"
query='{
  viewer {
    watching(first: 3, orderBy: {field: UPDATED_AT, direction: DESC}) {
      nodes {
        refs(refPrefix: "refs/heads/", orderBy: {direction: DESC, field: TAG_COMMIT_DATE}, last: 100) {
          nodes {
            target {
              ... on Commit {
                history(first: 10) {
                  ...CommitFragment
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  rateLimit {
    limit
    cost
    remaining
    resetAt
  }
}

fragment CommitFragment on CommitHistoryConnection {
  nodes {
    message
    author {
      name
      avatarUrl(size: 30)
    }
  }
}'
queryStr="${query//[$'\n|\r\n']}"

curl -s -H "Authorization: token $token" \
     -H  "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -d '{ 
          "query": "'"${queryStr//[\"]/\\\"}"'"
      }' https://api.github.com/graphql
```

In case of Javascript, if you use `XMLHttpRequest` :

```javascript
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://api.github.com/graphql";
http.open("POST", url, true);

http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
http.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "token YOUR_TOKEN");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}

http.send(JSON.stringify({
    "query": '{ viewer { watching(first: 3, orderBy: {field: UPDATED_AT, direction: DESC}) { nodes { refs(refPrefix: "refs/heads/", orderBy: {direction: DESC, field: TAG_COMMIT_DATE}, last: 100) { nodes { target { ... on Commit { history(first: 10) { ...CommitFragment } }}}}}}} rateLimit { limit cost remaining resetAt}}fragment CommitFragment on CommitHistoryConnection { nodes { message author { name avatarUrl(size: 30) } } }'
}));
```

You can also find examples using [apollo-client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48036597/2614364) and [graphql.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48468018/2614364)

Comment: Works perfectly for the curl version ! thank you for your answer !